# LightingColorFilter just working for some buttons

Tags: android, button, colors

I am trying a simple code to change the color of some buttons using LightingColorFilter. However, my code just changes the code for the buttons placed in position after the one I click.

For showing this behavior, I have created a simple listener that is called whenever a button is pressed (see code below). It is supposed to change all buttons to red. Oddly enough, if I click on the second button, just the number 2,3 and 4 change. If I click on 2, just 2,3,4. If I click on 4, just the 4.

I have tried this in the emulator, and in a real device with the same result.

Am I missing something in the code?

Thanks in advance,
Marcos Moreno.

```
public void botonOpcion(View v){
        LightingColorFilter rojo = new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFDD0000);


        bt_opc1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion1);
        bt_opc2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion2);
        bt_opc3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion3);
        bt_opc4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion4);

        bt_opc1.getBackground().setColorFilter(rojo);
        bt_opc2.getBackground().setColorFilter(rojo);
        bt_opc3.getBackground().setColorFilter(rojo);
        bt_opc4.getBackground().setColorFilter(rojo);
}
```

Comment: If I just add 'bt_opc1.invalidate();' before setting the filters, everything work as expected. Any idea of why? Thank you!

Comment: That's pretty weird behavior.  I'm glad you found a workaround.